# making .exe using native bundle not work for 32 bit

Tags: javafx

i make an desktop application using javafx, i make an .exe file using native bundle in netbeans 8.1 , this .exe file work proper in 64 bit computer , but in 32 bit computer makes an error like " MSVCR100.dll is either designed to run on windows or it contains an error "

Comment: What are the dependencies?  What settings did you use to build your executable?  Can you provide us with enough information to duplicate the error?

Answer (score 0):

You must create it on a 32 bit computer as specified [here](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/native_pkg.html)

Answer (score -1):

I use netbeans version 8.1, jdk 8, I used innoSetUp for producing EXE installer on windows , and make exe file using native bundle from netbeans , i make exe file for 32 bit in 32 bit OS also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF7kA.)but make error MSVCR100.dll [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsGOE.png)

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOIoe.png)

Comment: Why you did not use install4J ?

Comment: You should edit your question if you wanted to add more detail. You should not add more detail in an answer. Delete this and make it apart of your question.